# Give structure to 'random' function js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array and a function that picks randomly elements from this array and displays them in a div.

My array:

```
var testarray = [A, B, C, D, E, F];
```

Part of the js function:

```
var new_word = testarray[Math.floor((Math.random()*testarray.length)+1)];
$("#stimuli").text(new_word);
```

My question is, is there a way I can have them picked randomly in a certain ratio/order?
For example, that if I have my function executed 12 times, that each of the six letters is displayed exactly twice, and that there can never be the same letter displayed twice in a row?

Comment: google "permutation of array elements", it will surely yield some good example.

Comment: You should remove the +1: Math.floor(Math.random()*testarray.length)

Comment: @MauricePerry But does this accomplish all what I want? Non-repeating and picking each exactly twice?

Comment: No, it would just prevent an index overflow.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

To your question in the comment: Of course there are hundreds ways to solve a problem. Think about using artificial intelligence, a mathematical algorithm or the answers given by others here. It depends on what you really want to achieve. I just gave a robust solution that is easy to understand and implement..

Here's another (different approach), same result but with the prevention that values displays twice in a row.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/jJE7F/
Code:

```
function StructuredRandom(arr, nDisplay)
{
    //    storage array.
    this.mVar           =    [];
    this.previous;

    //    add it in the storage.
    for (var i in arr)
        for (var j=0; j<nDisplay; j++)
            this.mVar.push(arr[i]);

    //    shuffle it, making it 'random'.
    for(var a, b, c = this.mVar.length; c; a = Math.floor(Math.random() * c), b = this.mVar[--c], this.mVar[c] = this.mVar[a], this.mVar[a] = b);

    //    call this when you want the next item.
    this.next          =    function()
    {
        //    default value if empty.
        if (this.mVar.length==0) return 0;

        //    if this is the last element...
        if (this.mVar.length==1)
        {
            //    we must give it..
            return this.mVar.pop();

            //    or give a default value,
            //    because we can't 'control' re-occuring values.
            return -1;
        }

        //    fetch next element.
        var element    =    this.mVar.pop();

        //    check if this was already given before.
        if  (element==this.previous)
        {
            //    put it on top if so.
            this.mVar.unshift(element);

            //    call the function again for next number.
            return this.next();
        }

        //    set 'previous' for next call.
        this.previous     =    element;

        //    give an element if not.
        return element;
    };
}
```

**NOTE:** In this example we can't fully control that the same values are displayed twice.. This is because we can control the first numbers, but when there is only one number left to display, we must either give it or display a default value for it, thus there is a chance that the same value is shown.

Good luck!

---

Like this?

```
var arr         =     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],  //    array with random values.
    maxDispl    =     2,                //    max display.
    arr2        =     init(arr)        //    storage.
;

//    create object of given array.
function init(arr)
{
    var pop = [];

    for (var i in arr)
    {
        pop.push({value:arr[i], displayed:0});
    }

    return pop;
}

//    show random number using global var arr2.
function showRandom()
{
    //    return if all numbers has been given.
    if (arr2.length<1)    return;

    var randIndex=    Math.floor(Math.random()*arr2.length);

    if (arr2[randIndex].displayed<maxDispl)
    {
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML+=arr2[randIndex].value + ', ';
        arr2[randIndex].displayed++;
    }
    else
    {
        //    remove from temp array.
        arr2.splice(randIndex, 1);

        //    search for a new random.
        showRandom();
    }
}

// iterate the function *maxDispl plus random.
var length  = (arr.length*maxDispl) + 2;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    showRandom();
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/JfV77/3/

Comment: This looks great, but is this the only way? Plus: in your script they can repeat each other directly after.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a quasi-random sequence.   These sequences have the properties you're after.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence